# Opencart SagePay extension issue

Tags: opencart, cloudflare, opayo

I worked for my client on Opencart Version 2.3.0.2 around 6 month ago. I enabled the sagepay payment extension. Sagepay extension was working fine from last 6 month but suddenly stopped working. when I debug the code I am not getting any response from SagePay payment processor. After completion of request I am getting the error with response code 522. Please see the image. [image]

Anybody Please help?

Thanks

Comment: There are 3 different sagepay extensions, which one are you using?  If you need help debugging you should include the relevant code, especially curl request parameters.

Comment: I am using "Sage Payment Solutions (US)". yes , request already sending using CURL but I am not getting any response.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are using Cloudflare (https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171906-Error-522-Connection-timed-out)

522 is basically a code for "go away, we don't like your request or something seems wrong"

It could be anything from their server being busy to a Cloudflare issue.

However looking at the US Sagepay code the curl request is pretty crude, no SSL validation, no request headers - and even has a card number data in it (I do hope you know your PCI requirements for that!).

The Ray ID you got is basically a receipt from cloudflare for the incident - contact SagePay US first, explain the issue (they may already be aware and need to add your server IP to cloudflare). If you get the "its an OpenCart problem", its not - if they do say that please let me know!

If the support is in a helpful mood they will take the Ray ID, ask their tech team to contact CF and find out what the problem was, if it genuinely was ANYthing other than a server was down/unavailable (but that's hard to believe for companies like that now) then they should be able to advise you further.

Hope this helps!